# Multiple Slide Out Menus Issues

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm creating a page with multiple slide out menus. Eventually, there will be one on the right left and bottom. Currently, I'm have a few issues.

- The `content` div is not moving to the right when the menu is selected. The menu icon moves, but the div doesn't move.
- I'd like to have them both visible at the same time, but instead of appending the appropriate open/close class to the `body`, my js is changing the class.

```js
/*
  Slidemenu
*/
(function() {
 var $body = document.body,
       $left_menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('left-menu-trigger')[0];

 if ( typeof $left_menu_trigger !== 'undefined' ) {
  $left_menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
   $body.className = ( $body.className == 'left-menu-active' )? '' : 'left-menu-active';
  });
 }

}).call(this);

(function() {
 var $body = document.body,
       $right_menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('right-menu-trigger')[0];

 if ( typeof $right_menu_trigger !== 'undefined' ) {
  $right_menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
   $body.className = ( $body.className == 'right-menu-active' )? '' : 'right-menu-active';
  });
 }

}).call(this);

// Create the Google Map…
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.0756, -70.7606),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700);
/*
  Fonts
*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ico';
  src: url("data:application/octet-stream;base64,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") format("woff"), url("data:application/octet-stream;base64,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") format("truetype");
}
/*
  Globals
*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #556270;
  color: #353d46;
  font: 18px/27px 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: #FF6B6B;
  margin: 0 0 27px;
}

/*
  LEFT MENU
*/
nav#left-slide-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li {
  color: #dfe5eb;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li:hover {
  color: #59e9df;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li:before {
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  color: #59e9df;
  margin-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1em;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.sep {
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b7b8d;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.timeline:before {
  content: '\e805';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.events:before {
  content: '\e802';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.calendar:before {
  content: '\e800';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.settings:before {
  content: '\e803';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.logout:before {
  content: '\e804';
}

body.left-menu-active nav#left-slide-menu {
  left: 0px;
}

body.left-menu-active nav#left-slide-menu ul {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

div#content div.left-menu-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #dfe5eb;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
div#content div.left-menu-trigger:before {
  content: '\e801';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 36px;
}

div#content div.left-menu-trigger:hover {
  background: #556270;
}

div#content div.left-menu-trigger:hover:before {
  color: #fcfeff;
}

body.left-menu-active div#content {
  left: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
}

body.left-menu-active div#content .left-menu-trigger {
  left: 210px;
}

/*
  RIGHT MENU
*/
nav#right-slide-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li {
  color: #dfe5eb;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li:hover {
  color: #59e9df;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li:before {
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  color: #59e9df;
  margin-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1em;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.sep {
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b7b8d;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.timeline:before {
  content: '\e805';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.events:before {
  content: '\e802';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.calendar:before {
  content: '\e800';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.settings:before {
  content: '\e803';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.logout:before {
  content: '\e804';
}

body.right-menu-active nav#right-slide-menu {
  right: 0px;
}

body.right-menu-active nav#right-slide-menu ul {
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

div#content div.right-menu-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #dfe5eb;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
div#content div.right-menu-trigger:before {
  content: '\e801';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 36px;
}

div#content div.right-menu-trigger:hover {
  background: #556270;
}

div#content div.right-menu-trigger:hover:before {
  color: #fcfeff;
}

body.right-menu-active div#content {
  right: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
}

body.right-menu-active div#content .right-menu-trigger {
  right: 160px;
}


/*
  Content
*/
div#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #fcfeff;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

div#map {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>AC Directions</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_/base.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="directions.css">
</head>

<body>

   <!-- LEFT SLIDE MENU -->
   <nav id="left-slide-menu">
    <ul>
     <li class="timeline">Timeline</li>
     <li class="events">Events</li>
     <li class="calendar">Calendar</li>
     <li class="sep settings">Settings</li>
     <li class="logout">Logout</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

   <!-- RIGHT SLIDE MENU -->
   <nav id="right-slide-menu">
      <ul>
         <li class="timeline">Timeline</li>
         <li class="events">Events</li>
         <li class="calendar">Calendar</li>
         <li class="sep settings">Settings</li>
         <li class="logout">Logout</li>
      </ul>
   </nav>

   <!-- CONTENT -->
   <div id="content">
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div class="left-menu-trigger"></div>
      <div class="right-menu-trigger"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
   <script defer="defer" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <script defer="defer" src="directions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can simplify your code, or produce a new simple example in order to learn what you really want your code to do, so that you can apply the thing you learnt to your own code.

Comment: if you are not bothered about using plugins i recommend snap js for your panels -- http://jakiestfu.github.io/Snap.js/demo/apps/default.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first problem :**

remove `width: 100%` from `div#content`.

**For the second problem :**

change this line :

```
$body.className = ( $body.className == 'left-menu-active' )? '' : 'left-menu-active';
```

To :

```
$body.classList.toggle('left-menu-active');
```

And change this line too:

```
$body.className = ( $body.className == 'right-menu-active' )? '' : 'right-menu-active';
```

To :

```
$body.classList.toggle('right-menu-active');
```

This way you can have both of the menus visible at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, in `div#content`, if you delete `width: 100%;`, you can see the right side content appearing when you click the icon.

```js
/*
  Slidemenu
*/
(function() {
 var $body = document.body,
       $left_menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('left-menu-trigger')[0];

 if ( typeof $left_menu_trigger !== 'undefined' ) {
  $left_menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
   $body.className = ( $body.className == 'left-menu-active' )? '' : 'left-menu-active';
  });
 }

}).call(this);

(function() {
 var $body = document.body,
       $right_menu_trigger = $body.getElementsByClassName('right-menu-trigger')[0];

 if ( typeof $right_menu_trigger !== 'undefined' ) {
  $right_menu_trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
   $body.className = ( $body.className == 'right-menu-active' )? '' : 'right-menu-active';
  });
 }

}).call(this);

// Create the Google Map…
var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.0756, -70.7606),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700);
/*
  Fonts
*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ico';
  src: url("data:application/octet-stream;base64,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") format("woff"), url("data:application/octet-stream;base64,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") format("truetype");
}
/*
  Globals
*/
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #556270;
  color: #353d46;
  font: 18px/27px 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: #FF6B6B;
  margin: 0 0 27px;
}

/*
  LEFT MENU
*/
nav#left-slide-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li {
  color: #dfe5eb;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li:hover {
  color: #59e9df;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li:before {
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  color: #59e9df;
  margin-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1em;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.sep {
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b7b8d;
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.timeline:before {
  content: '\e805';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.events:before {
  content: '\e802';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.calendar:before {
  content: '\e800';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.settings:before {
  content: '\e803';
}
nav#left-slide-menu > ul li.logout:before {
  content: '\e804';
}

body.left-menu-active nav#left-slide-menu {
  left: 0px;
}

body.left-menu-active nav#left-slide-menu ul {
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

div#content div.left-menu-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #dfe5eb;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
div#content div.left-menu-trigger:before {
  content: '\e801';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 36px;
}

div#content div.left-menu-trigger:hover {
  background: #556270;
}

div#content div.left-menu-trigger:hover:before {
  color: #fcfeff;
}

body.left-menu-active div#content {
  left: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
}

body.left-menu-active div#content .left-menu-trigger {
  left: 210px;
}

/*
  RIGHT MENU
*/
nav#right-slide-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li {
  color: #dfe5eb;
  padding: 6px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li:hover {
  color: #59e9df;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li:before {
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  color: #59e9df;
  margin-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1em;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.sep {
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b7b8d;
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.timeline:before {
  content: '\e805';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.events:before {
  content: '\e802';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.calendar:before {
  content: '\e800';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.settings:before {
  content: '\e803';
}
nav#right-slide-menu > ul li.logout:before {
  content: '\e804';
}

body.right-menu-active nav#right-slide-menu {
  right: 0px;
}

body.right-menu-active nav#right-slide-menu ul {
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}

div#content div.right-menu-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #dfe5eb;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}
div#content div.right-menu-trigger:before {
  content: '\e801';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  color: black;
  font-family: "ico";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 36px;
}

div#content div.right-menu-trigger:hover {
  background: #556270;
}

div#content div.right-menu-trigger:hover:before {
  color: #fcfeff;
}

body.right-menu-active div#content {
  right: 150px;
  border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
}

body.right-menu-active div#content .right-menu-trigger {
  right: 160px;
}


/*
  Content
*/
div#content {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* width: 100%; *************************************/
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: #fcfeff;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  box-shadow: -3px 0 6px #4a5562;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

div#map {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title>AC Directions</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_/base.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="directions.css">
</head>

<body>

   <!-- LEFT SLIDE MENU -->
   <nav id="left-slide-menu">
    <ul>
     <li class="timeline">Timeline</li>
     <li class="events">Events</li>
     <li class="calendar">Calendar</li>
     <li class="sep settings">Settings</li>
     <li class="logout">Logout</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

   <!-- RIGHT SLIDE MENU -->
   <nav id="right-slide-menu">
      <ul>
         <li class="timeline">Timeline</li>
         <li class="events">Events</li>
         <li class="calendar">Calendar</li>
         <li class="sep settings">Settings</li>
         <li class="logout">Logout</li>
      </ul>
   </nav>

   <!-- CONTENT -->
   <div id="content">
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div class="left-menu-trigger"></div>
      <div class="right-menu-trigger"></div>
   </div>
   <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
   <script defer="defer" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
   <script defer="defer" src="directions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```